# Set IP preference in WinHTTP (c++)

Tags: winhttp

I have a code that is using WinHTTP on Windows 7.

The problem i'm experiencing is that the connction to specific hostname takes a long time when the user tries to use an IPv6 address (that is disabled).

I want to configure the connection (maybe WinHttpConnect parametrs) to try IPv4 *first*.

Is there a way to set the address binding order?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You cannot do this.

See [Specify which Network Card/Connection Winhttp Must Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463059/specify-which-network-card-connection-winhttp-must-use)